# Issue : SQL Azure connection is broken . After reconnecting and accessing entity object , An Error occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, azure-sql-database

Connected to website and keeping idle for 30 mins, then trying to access the entities I am getting the following error.

**Entity framework An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details . Inner exception {“Invalid object name 'dbo.TableName'.”}**

Sample Code

```
Static Class Azure
{
 public static CrmEntities ConnectCustomerEntity()
    {
        CrmEntities customerEntity = null;
        policy.ExecuteAction(() =>
           {
               try
               {
                   var shardId = GetShardId();

                   customerEntity = new CrmEntities(ConnectionStringCustomerDB());
                   string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION Customer_Federation(ShardId =" + shardId + ") WITH RESET, FILTERING=ON";

                   customerEntity.Connection.Open();                     
                   customerEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand(federationCmdText);   
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                  customerEntity.Connection.Close();
                  SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
                   //throw e;
               } 
           });
        return customerEntity;
    }

 public static CrmEntities DBConnect(CrmEntities _db)
    {
     try{
        if (_db == null)
            _db = Azure.ConnectCustomerEntity();
        if ((_db.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken) || (_db.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed))
        {               
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            _db = Azure.ConnectCustomerEntity();
        }
    else
        { //This code is to find out any issues in connection pool database connection
      string sqlCmdText = @"select top 1 Id from Project";
            _db.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlCmdText);
        }
        }
  catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _db.Connection.Close();
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            _db = Azure.ConnectCustomerEntity();
        }
        return _db;
}

}
```

Mvc Controller. The following code I am gettting that exception, after 30 mins

```
 public class FilterController : Controller
{  
public ActionResult GetFilters(string entityName,string typeFilter)
    {
       _crmEntities=Azure.DBConnect(_db);
        var query = _db.FilterFields.Where(filter => filter.TableId == tableId).ToList();  // Here I am getting that exception
     }
}
```

I dont know, Why i m getting that exception. I tried all possibilities. Nothing helped. I really struck with this. If anybody knows please tell your views to come out from this exception

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your session times out.

try to increase session timeout:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx

Comment: Kash, I am not using any session at all. Its only related with SQLAzure connection.